# Read in search strings from text file, search for string in second text file and output to CSV

Tags: csv, awk, scripting

I have a text file named file1.txt that is formatted like this:

```
001 , ID , 20000
002 , Name , Brandon
003 , Phone_Number , 616-234-1999
004 , SSNumber , 234-23-234
005 , Model , Toyota
007 , Engine ,V8
008 , GPS , OFF
```

and I have file2.txt formatted like this:

```
#==============================================
# 005 : Model
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Model] = Honda
option = 0
length = 232
time = 1000
hp = 75.0
k1 = 0.3
k2 = 0.0
k1 = 0.3
k2 = 0.0
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Model] = Toyota
option = 1
length = 223
time = 5000
speed = 50
CCNA = 1
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Model] = Miata
option = 2
CCNA = 1
#==============================================
# 007 : Engine
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Engine_Type] = V8                 #1200HP
option = 0
p = 12.0
pp = 12.0
map = 0.4914
k1mat = 100
k2mat = 600
value =12.00
mep = 79.0
cylinders = 8
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Engine_Type] = v6                 #800HP
option = 1
active = 1
cylinders = 6
lim = 500
lim = 340
rpm = 330
start = 350
ul = 190.0
ll = 180.0
ul = 185.0
#==============================================
# 008 : GPS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[GPS] = ON
monitor = 0
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[GPS] = OFF
monitor = 1
Enable = 1
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[GPS] = Only
monitor = 2
Enable = 1
#==============================================
# 014 :Option
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Option] = Disable
monitor = 0
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Option] = Enable
monitor = 1
#==============================================
# 015 : Weight
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[lbs] = &1
weight = &1
#==============================================
```

The expected output is supposed to look like this:
Since there is only option 005-008 in file1.txt the output would be:

```
Code:
#==============================================
# 005 : Model
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Model] = Toyota
option = 1
length = 223
time = 5000
speed = 50
CCNA = 1
#==============================================
# 007 : Engine
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Engine_Type] = V8                 #1200HP
option = 0
p = 12.0
pp = 12.0
map = 0.4914
k1mat = 100
k2mat = 600
value =12.00
mep = 79.0
cylinders = 8
#==============================================
# 008 : GPS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[GPS] = OFF
monitor = 1
Enable = 1
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, using Awk and the values from the 2nd and 3rd columns in file1, I want to search for those strings in file2 and output everything in that section to a CSV file ie from where the string is found to where there is the #-------------
demarcation.

Could someone please help me with this and explain also? I am new to Awk

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't really use awk for this job as specified, but here's a little snippet to get started:

```
awk -F'[ ,]+' 'FNR == NR { section["[" $2 "]"] = $3; next }
               /^\[/ && section[$1] == $3, /^#/' file1.txt file2.txt
```

1) The `-F'[ ,]+'` sets the field separator to one or more of spaces and/or commas (since `file1.txt` looks like it's not a proper CSV file).

2) `FNR == NR` (record number in file equals total record number) is only true when reading `file1.txt`. So for each line in `file1.txt`, we record `[second_field]` as the pattern to look for with the third field as value.

3) Then we look for lines that begin with a `[` and where the value stored in `section` for the first field of that line matches the third field of that line (`/^\[/ && section[$1] == $3`), and print from that line until the next line that begins with a `#`.

The output for your example input is:

```
[Model] = Toyota
option = 1
length = 223
time = 5000
speed = 50
CCNA = 1
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[GPS] = OFF
monitor = 1
Enable = 1
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The matched lines in step 3 were `[Model] = Toyota` and `[GPS] = OFF`. The `Engine` line is missing because `file2.txt` had `Engine_Type` instead. Also, I didn't bother with the section headers; it would be easy to add another condition to print them all but it requires lookahead to print only the ones that are going to have matching content in them (because at the time you read the header you don't know if a match is found inside). For that, I would switch to another language (e.g., Ruby).

Comment: thank you for your help and the explanations. I am going to begin work on this and ask further questions if I get stuck.

Comment: Also, if I want to write it as a self contained script that can be run from the command line, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @user2056389 Put it in a file, make it executable, and first line: `#!/usr/bin/env awk -f`